# DataTables Ajax add link to json array

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, datatables

So this is my json output 
{"draw": 1, "recordsTotal": 2, "recordsFiltered": 2, "data": [["2014-08-01","34","84"],["2014-08-02","36","61"]]}

and using DataTable I can build my tables

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>2014-08-01</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>84</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>2014-08-02</td>
   <td>36</td>
   <td>61</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

well thats my table you get the picture... so the first column is a date, and second is an ID and the 3rd is just a value... I'd like to add a link to the ID

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>2014-08-01</td>
      <td><a href="foo.php?id=34">34</a></td>
      <td>84</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2014-08-02</td>
      <td><a href="foo.php?id=36">36</a></td>
      <td>61</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

and this is the code I use for the "ajax"

```
$('#tr1').dataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "bServerSide": false,
            "sAjaxSource": "rep/cm.php?pm",
            "sServerMethod": "GET",
            "wPaginationType": "full_numbers"
        });
```

So, how do I add that link?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your file "rep/cm.php?pm" to return a different json array which already contains the links instead of the page id numbers.

This should be your json output:

```
{"draw": 1, "recordsTotal": 2, "recordsFiltered": 2, "data": [["2014-08-01","<a href=\"foo.php?id=34\">34</a>","84"],["2014-08-02","<a href=\"foo.php?id=36\">36</a>","61"]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `aoColumnDefs` together with `mData` and `mRender` look at [DataTAbles](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns).
 `mData` and `mRender` allows to manipulate data for display without altering the underlying data for the table.

```
$('#tr1').dataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "bServerSide": false,
            "sAjaxSource": "rep/cm.php?pm",
            "sServerMethod": "GET",
            "wPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aoColumnDefs": [
                { "aTargets": [1], "mData":1,
                   "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
                     return '<a href="foo.php?id='+ data +'">'+ data + '</a>';
                   }},
            ]
        });
```